# Pivot Table Label filter - Multiple values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

How do I add a filter to a Pivot Table to filter out multiple values?

Using the Label > Does Not Contain filter I want to exclude "apples OR pears OR oranges".

What is the syntax for that?

Comment: Please add more context. Are you looking for a VBA solution?

Comment: Not a VBA solution no.  Just a way to apply the above criteria simply with the dropdown filter function of a Pivot Table